# htaccess original rewrites already used

Tags: .htaccess

Ok so I have a website that already takes the SEO'd URLs and parses the info so that I can get the content for them on their respective pages.

the code in the htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(email)/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html /page.php?seo_title=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(email)/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html /page.php?seo_title=$2&seo_parent=$1 [L]
```

So now a couple of pages have changed from:

old-parent-name/seo-title.html to new-parent-name/seo-title.html

but when i try to do any type of regular 301 redirect, the URL string ends up like this:

http://www.example.com/new-parent/old-seo-title.html?seo_title=old-seo-title&seo_parent=new-parent

Is there any way to do this so that the Query String does not appear?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this above the rules that you have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(email)/
RewriteRule ^old-parent-name/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html /new-seo-parent/$1.html [L,R=301]
```